# RewriteRule: match only first occurance of a string. Match /mystring but not /some/path/to/mystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^mystringtoreplace/?$ http://www.example.com/some/other/path/mystringtoreplace [L]
```

Intention is to redirect http://www.example.com/mystringtoreplace to http://www.example.com/some/other/path/mystringtoreplace.

What I get is a too many redirects error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

How can I write a correct RewriteRule for that problem?

Comment: Are there any other rules?

Comment: @hjpotter92 The rewrite was added to a WordPress site. I found out that the permalink of http://www.example.com/some/other/path/mystringtoreplace was in fact set to http://www.example.com/mystringtoreplace So WordPress redirected to /mystringtoreplace and my rule redirected to /some/other/path/mystringtoreplace. That resulted in the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the RewriteRule is correct. There was a problem with WordPress Permalink. See comment above.